# Why is there a time delay in loading my webpage project in android studio?

Tags: android

In my web App project on android studio, when i run the project on emulator or external mobile device for testing, there is a delay in loading. Does anyone know why and who can proffer a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by delay? You mean loading the website?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean actually. Yes there is a delay in loading the website

Comment: You do know the concept of website content having to be loaded, right?

Comment: I don't follow, please explain in simple terms what you mean by and i quote "You do know the concept of website content having to be loaded, right?"

Comment: It takes some time to load a website.

Comment: So its okay the delay am getting from it then, Okay i just hope it doesn't stall me when wanting to publish on playstore because it is a strong criteria. Other web-incoported apps like facebook doesn't take that long to load even with a splashscreen, it displays immediately. i was hoping i could get a solution that will make it faster.